# D-link 1360 Access point and Repeater mode

Tags: wireless-access-point, repeater

I have 7 dlink routers, 1 for library and 1 for reception, both in opposite end and has different SSID and 5 for public. One dlink is in each room.

The 5 dlinks, I setup 1 as access point and 4 as repeaters.

problem:

This dlink Public has only 1 access point and 4 in repeater mode. as I observed there is a problem of the repeater next to reception room. It can connect to 6 iPads and 10 smart phones but not stable and intermittent connection. When I turn on the repeater no.4 next to reception it is showing warning sign and no internet access or limited.

my setup: (public dlink)

- no password key
- disable WPS
- same SSID
- DHCP mode
- schedule 7am-5pm

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to change **Channel B/G** of this modem.
2. If problem exist yet, Change this Dlink with another one and check the problem, If problem solved maybe that modem has been damaged.
3. If problem exist yet! You have interferes in your signals and there is a signal which disturbing your WiFi Communication. Some thing like telephones.